# Revel not working with GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT?

Tags: go, revel

I'm using revel together with GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT. This implies that my revel package is located in the vendor folder inside my project folder:

```
$GOPATH\src\myproject\vendor\github.com\revel
```

Revel and my project build correctly. Go implicitly changes the revel imports to:

```
"myproject/vendor/github.com/revel/revel
```

However, when I go to run my project, revel tries to import from the standard GOPATH. It does not recognize that I have GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT turned on.

```
c:\WorkspaceGo\go\src\myproject>revel run myproject
~
~ revel! http://revel.github.io
~
ERROR 2015/12/20 09:51:27 revel.go:281: Failed to find Revel with error: 
cannot find package "github.com/revel/revel" in any of:
    C:\Go\src\github.com\revel\revel (from $GOROOT)
    c:\WorkspaceGo\go\src\github.com\revel\revel (from $GOPATH)
```

How can I make revel recognize GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT so that it uses the correct GOPATH?

Comment: This appears to be a problem with go/build not honoring GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT. See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12278